How to make callbacks from C code to Tcl that returns data to C
I faced with the issue - I have C code of optimization library, and it accepts pointer to function as one of the argument. So, previously I used SWIG to generate Tcl wrapper of for C functions, but in this case I need to call Tcl function from C. Each time callback is invoked, it calculates the values of the functions with particular parameters as its arguments. I want to call Tcl procedure for that, and it should be done inside the same interpreter I call the C optimization procedure, and then return data back to C program.
I found that it is not possible with SWIG without modifying C source code and some typemaps hacks. What are the other options? I checked Critcl, but there I again have to modify and reorder C source code. The only viable option I see now is direct use of Tcl C API.
Are there any other ways to accomplish that? Thank you.

What's wrong with direct use of Tcl's C API?  Or even just writing the whole thing in C, since that's the language of both the optimization library you want to use and the callbacks you want to use?

Not an issue, just need to learn this API in details, which was avoided until this time :)

And also the fact that in that case I need to write wrapper for the rest of functionality, which SWIG does for me. Maybe it is absolutely legal to mix SWIG wrapper with TCL C API functions in C code...?

The SWIG-generated wrappers will be implemented via the Tcl C API. And I think Tcl itself uses the API internally.  There's no particular reason why that should present a problem for other calls to the same API.

The best way to call a Tcl command from C is the API function Tcl_EvalObjv(). You need an interpreter context to call that, and the command name and other arguments to the command are passed in an array of Tcl_Obj* handles (the box type that contains all Tcl values). This method of calling has the lowest overheads, but values passed must have a non-zero reference count (i.e., call Tcl_IncrRefCount on them before and Tcl_DecrRefCountafterwards).
Otherwise, build a string and call Tcl_Eval() (or a Tcl value and call Tcl_EvalObj()). These incur additional overheads, such as needing to parse the string.
You can manufacture Tcl_Obj* handles using calls such as Tcl_NewIntObj() or Tcl_ObjPrintf().
See https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Eval.htm for more options for calling commands from C.
The returned data will be in the interpreter result if the result code is TCL_OK, and can be retrieved with Tcl_GetObjResult() or discarded with Tcl_ResetResult(). Calls like Tcl_GetIntFromObj() can be used to unbox the value.
